# pass comma separated string to in clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to pass comma separated string to `IN` clause. My controller code is as:-

```
        $batchpost = $this->input->post('batch');//print_r($batch);

        $batch_id = '';
        for($i=0;$i<count($batchpost);$i++ ) {
            $batch_id = $batch_id . $batchpost[$i] . ',';
        }
        $batch_string = rtrim($batch_id, ',');
        $batch = str_replace(",", ",", $batch_string) ;

        $list = $this->admin_model->get_attendance_datatables($batch);
```

Here `$batchpost` will return array value, and I want to convert it to a comma separated string and pass to the model.

My model code is as:-

```
    $this->db->select('offline_student.*,batch.batch_name,offline_course.course');
    $this->db->from($this->table8);
    $this->db->join('offline_course', 'offline_course.id = offline_student.course', 'left');
    $this->db->join('batch', 'batch.id = offline_student.batch', 'left');                
    $this->db->where('offline_student.status', 'Active');
    $this->db->where_in('batch.id', $batch);
    $this->db->order_by('offline_student.id', 'asc');
```

Suppose in a row for batch column having two value(2,3)in database, if I pass only '2' or '2,3' to model, query will return my result, but when i pass only 3, It's not showing that record.

Comment: `$batch` should be an `array` if you want to put it into `where_in` clause

Comment: I am already convert $batchpost to a comma separated string

Comment: `$batch = explode(',', $batch);`

Comment: try to `echo` your query by changing any table field name to wrong name and see how your query looks like in SQL.

Comment: that is what you don't need to do it, just pass as an array into `where_in`

Comment: Record will show but that particular record not showing ,means when i pass only 3 to in clause instead of 2 or 2,3.

Comment: Yes i will try to pass array into in clause but same thing happen.

Comment: show your `print_r($batch);` data

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 31
)

Comment: @dipti is it 3,1 or 31. if  it is 31 then simply use  `$batch = $this->input->post('batch');`  `$this->db->where_in('offline_student.batch', $batch);`

Comment: no it will return 31,yes i pass this but this record not show.in my data base one record has two batch 1&31 if i pass 1 or 1,31 it will show but if i pass only 31 it not showing that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following lines:

```
$batch_id = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($batchpost);$i++ ) { 
    $batch_id = $batch_id . $batchpost[$i] . ','; 
} 
$batch_string = rtrim($batch_id, ','); 
$batch = str_replace(",", ",", $batch_string) ;
```

...and make it like this:

```
$batchpost = $this->input->post('batch');//print_r($batch); 
$list = $this->admin_model->get_attendance_datatables($batchpost);
```

you don't need to convert `$batchpost` to comma separated string, because `where_in()` method expects an array on it's second param.

See the docs of `where_in()`, here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data